# How To: Eclipse Maven install build jar with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3, m2eclipse

I am using Eclipse Maven (m2e) inside Eclipse and I am running my project like this:

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ro.project</groupId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ro.project</name>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</org.hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>ro.project.ProjectServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.0_02</version>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ant-magic</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                                <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath" />
                                <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />

                                <ant antfile="${basedir}/clientExport.xml" target="export-all" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <artifactId>project-core</artifactId>
    <url>http://www.project.ro</url>
</project>
```

After I run the maven install it is working...

Maven run configurations:

[image: maven install deploy jar]

The problem is that my generated `.jar` it doesn't have the dependencies included....
How can I configure `pom.xml` to include all my dependencies in `.jar` format and not unpacked.. because it seems that unpacked are not working correct...

To be sure that including all jars is ok.. I downloaded and added each library into `jar`'s `/lib` folder and the jar is running... so.. my only question is: How can I configure `pom.xml` in order to add all my dependencies in `jar` format?

I tried all methods:

1. `assembly:assembly`
2. `assembly:single`
3. `assembly:single` with my descriptor (an `assemble.xml` file) but it wasn't working
4. `maven copy dependencies` plugin but still not working with Eclipse Maven - `m2e`

I am out of solutions... can anyone tell me a proper way to add my dependencies in jar? I can't believe that `maven` is so complex and I can't find an answer to my question everywhere..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Unless you have a jar-loading classloader you can't nest jars like it sounds like you're trying to do.

Comment: I am going to run it like java -jar myjar

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

**1)** If you want an uber-jar (repacked with all dependencies), look into using and configuring the [*maven-shade-plugin*](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/):

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.group.id.Launcher1</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This will unpack all dependencies and merge them into one JAR file.

**2)** If you want to deliver a bundle (zip, tar.gz, etc) with the unpacked JAR files in the bundle (perhaps under lib/) then you need to look into the [*maven-assembly-plugin*](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/):

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-distro</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Note that this requires an assembly descriptor `src/main/assembly/dist.xml` and example looks like this:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
      <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>

      <includes>
        <include>com.group.id:project-launch1</include>
        <include>com.group.id:project-launch2</include>
      </includes>

    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
      <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>

      <includes>
        <include>com.group.id:project-lib1</include>
        <include>com.group.id:project-lib2</include>
        <include>com.group.id:project-lib3</include>
        <include>com.group.id:project-lib4</include>
      </includes>

    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

And since you are now assembling dependencies, you have better define the dependency in the pom.xml, like so:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-launch1</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-launch2</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-lib1</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    ... and so on ...
  </dependencies>
```

**3)** If you are delivering a bundle with an executable JAR file launcher, you will likely need to add a [*maven-jar-plugin*](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) configuration in addition to the *maven-assembly-plugin*:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-lib1</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-lib2</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-lib3</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    ... and so on ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <compress>true</compress>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.group.id.Launcher1</mainClass>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Note that the "addClasspath" directive adds the project dependencies to the class path. This is needed for JAR launchers, as they explicitly ignore all CLASSPATH environmental variables.

Comment: The average jar can contain jars, but the class loader doesn't load jars from within jars, so it's either an uber-jar or a "package" of files with appropriate relative locations.

Comment: thank you for your answer...
I want to deliver a `jar` that I can execute with `java -jar myProject.jar`... 
What you told me here is not adding my packages... how can I do that? thank you a lot... I want also to set my `classpath` in the jar...

Comment: now... it is adding my `libs` in a `zip` folder(or jar) but my project isn't there.. the result is something like: `project-1.0.SNAPSHOT`(inside is only a lib folder) **and** `META-INF`

Comment: @Alex. Set `<useProjectArtifact>` to `true` in the assembly descriptor to package the project artifacts as well.

Comment: @Alex Maven has a "one thing" "one project" rule which is part of its design.  To make this work, if you haven't done it already, you need two projects.  One to build the runnable jar, and a second to build the zip file.  The runnable jar has dependencies on the libraries it will need, but it _will not_ include them in the jar file.  It will include references to them in the ClassPath entry in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file (../lib/lib1.jar and so on).  The zip file will also depend on those libs, and the runnable jar.  The zip file project will then just build the zip with files in place.

Comment: aaaaaah, ok.. thank you... I didn't know that.. I thought that there might be a way to generate a single jar that contains everything... :(... I am disappointed by maven :(

Comment: @Alex Every tool has its wrinkles.  Maven has excellent dependency management, so it sort of makes sense to have it manage the dependent elements of the zip file (the runnable jar, the other libraries) using its dependency management.  However, that does mean you can get a lot more "little" maven projects instead of one big project (like you might do with ant).  Your initial request _exactly as you requested it_ "a single jar that contains jars" was not workable anyway, because Java's class loader cannot load Jar files out of Jar files, it can only load class files out of Jar files.