# How to make the spring maven project jar containing external jars work

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I have a jar `locator1.1`. On extracting the jar I can see the lib folder containing all the required jars. I also have the `applicationContext-locator.xml` in the locator1.1 folder.

The Manifest file shows

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
    Created-By: Apache Maven
    Built-By: abc
    Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55
    Main-Class: com.abc.Locator
    Class-Path: ./ lib/activemq-all-5.8.0.jar lib/activemq-amqp-5.8.0.jar 
     lib/activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar lib/activemq-openwire-legacy-5.8.0.jar 
     lib/proton-jms-0.3.0-fuse-2.jar lib/proton-0.3.0-fuse-2.jar lib/proto....
     lib/spring-core-3.2......
 .4.RELEASE.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/spring-jmx-2.0.8.jar
  lib/spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-3.2.4.REL
```

But on running the jar using `java -jar locator1.1.jar`. I am getting the following error. But all the required spring jars are there in the lib

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put all required jars in a lib folder inside the final jar with Maven ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758594/how-to-put-all-required-jars-in-a-lib-folder-inside-the-final-jar-with-maven)

Comment: @RC. the correct answer marked in the link suggests that it is not possible to do so "i found out that this is not workable solution because the class loader doesn't load jars from within jars" Is that what you suggest.