# Netbeans runtime configuration in jar

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jni4net

I have a maven project and jni4net is one of the dependency and it's running fine in Netbeans. But when i package it into a jar i get the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jni4net.n-0.8.8.0 in java.library.path`. I solved this problem in Netbenas by setting Working directory and VM Options in Project Properties -> Run. Now is there a way to include these configurations while packaging it as jar, or any other solution.
Thanks in advance...

Here is my pom

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>base</artifactId>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <name>BASE</name>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>repo</id>
          <url>file://${project.basedir}/./temp-repo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

      <dependencies> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jni4net</groupId>
            <artifactId>jni4net.j</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>customId</groupId>
            <artifactId>customId</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
           <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.5</version>
       </dependency>
      </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/lib
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                <mainClass>com.mysite.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>          
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>lib</directory>
                                        <!--<filtering>true</filtering>-->
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>              
                            </configuration>            
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Netbeans normally just adds all dependencies automatically when you clean & build?

Comment: Thanks for this quicky @rabbit guy, but when i am running my jar with java -jar in command prompt it's giving me the above error...

Comment: did you clean and build the project? You should have a `dist` folder in the application folder that Netbeans made and that .jar is what you should be running. The `dist` folder should have an additional folder in it called `lib` that contains all libraries needed to run.

Comment: There is no dist folder in maven project @rabbit guy

Comment: Doh... sorry. You are correct. Wasn't even considering that.

Comment: Try opening the jar that maven builds and check 1) tha the library is in the lib folder in the jar, and 2) The lib folder is referenced in the Manifest.

Comment: There is no lib folder and no reference of it in Manifest, how to do it, what plugin would i need to do it.@jr593

Comment: Considering your suggestions @jr593 i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25116745/4405431) answer, still there is no lib folder in jar but there is an reference for lib in MANIFEST