# Invoking browser from netbeans and jar act different

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

i am browsing a url in my default browser with this code..

```
    URI uri = new URI("Some url here"); 
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.browse(uri);
```

Running it from Netbeans opens the webpage flawlessly, but while running the jar it opens the folder where it is saved. Whats wrong. It's a maven project and here is the [pom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38744185/4405431). Thanks in advance..

Comment: What url are you trying and what url does the browser show?

Comment: Thank you @Thomas for your quick reply url is https://accounts.google.com/