# How to put all required jars in a lib folder inside the final jar with Maven without provided jars?

Tags: maven-3

I've read the question [How do I put all required JAR files in a library folder inside the final JAR file with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758594/how-to-put-all-required-jars-in-a-lib-folder-inside-the-final-jar-with-maven) and the answer

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <!-- <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix> -->
                <!-- <mainClass>test.org.Cliente</mainClass> -->
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

provides just what que OP is questioning.

Is it possible to do that without including dependencies declared as provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>` under `<overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>`

Comment: Wouldn't it be `<excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>`? That's what's Eclipse suggested me after I tried your answer and worked like a charm. Edit your answer and I'll have it as the accepted one.