# How to have a final jar with the dependency inside that jar in the jar format?

Tags: java, maven, classloader, serena

I need a configuration for Maven where all the libraries inside the project are in the final jar in the jar format... So i need to have jars inside the final jar. For that i can only use maven. I already tried without success with plugins like one-jar.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create only one jar which should contain all the classes from your application and third party libraries ?

Comment: Yes but i don't want to have the libraries unpacked in the .class files.

Comment: Is it possible to tell why you need jars inside the jar and not class

Comment: Because the agency i work for use Serena to deploy the programs and when Serena explode(extract) the jar file in a directory i need to have in this directory the jar files and not the .class

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758594/how-do-i-put-all-required-jar-files-in-a-library-folder-inside-the-final-jar-fil?rq=1 ?

Comment: No because in that question they want to put the jar library files in a directory outside the final jar so its different. I need them to be inside the final jar.

Comment: one-jar should really be the right solution, see https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/ if not, can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a `fat jar` that includes all you `jar` files, add the following code to your `pom.xml`. When you `clean and build` the project this will automatically make a `fat jar` file. You need to give your `main class` inside `<mainClass>` tag. That's it.

```
<project>
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                      <archive>
                          <manifest>
                              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                              <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
                          </manifest>
                      </archive>
                      <descriptorRefs>
                          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                      </descriptorRefs>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>final-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>single</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Does it contain multiple jar files inside one jar file ?

Comment: @Sambit Yes. It will make `fat.jar` file

Comment: I know it will create fat jar, but does that fat jar contain other jar files ?

Comment: It contains all the dependencies. (Other jars) Binds all dependencies to the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for nested jar because I haven't tried yet.

But I have created .jar file with all project dependencies(specified in pom file)

Try following mvn command in terminal...

**mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package**