# When run example.app file on mac it through error in java - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, build, packager

I am new in java development. Creating demo project using java + javafx + maven in eclipse it is working fine and able to connect embedded database sqlite and run query easily. But when I created build through jpackager following commands

`project location > mvn clean`

`mvn package`

`sh/link.sh -e`

`sh/create-appimage.sh -e`

Successfully created mac build when I run this javafx screen comes out but it's not table to connect org.sqlite.JDBC. It gives Exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC`.  I have checked maven pom.xml file that already added sqlite jar file. 
Please help me. Is any thing I am missing or in deployment this JDBC driver will not work ? Is there any other method to connect ?

JDBC configuration in my code is

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/example.db";

public static Connection getConnection()  {
    Connection conn = null;

        // STEP 2: Register jdbc drive

        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        // STEP 3 : Open a connetion

        System.out.println("connecting to database....");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: did you add it to the pom.xml like a dependency, or like a librery jar?

Comment: Yes, I added in pom.xml like <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.30.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: try setting this version, 3.15.1

Comment: Same error, No change.

Comment: I think your problem is that when you compile and run you are not adding your dependencies to the class path, or it doesn't know about them. When maven builds the jar it doesn't include the dependencies in the build - at least not automatically from my experience. You want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758594/how-do-i-put-all-required-jar-files-in-a-library-folder-inside-the-final-jar-fil

At least that would explain it working in eclipse and not after mvn clean install

Comment: you get sure, when you add a dependecy it must be like that  <scope>provided</scope> or without this tag

Comment: Thank you. I have also tried with scope tag. I think @DamianWillmer saying right it is related to maven dependency and I missing some plugin which also add sqlite in build. I will try and let you know if it works. Thanks

Comment: I have tried by many ways as well as to ensure sqlite jar is inside jar or not So I run command jar tf example.jar and found file here  lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar  but problem is same ( org.sqlite.JDBC class not found ).

Comment: share me your code, if it is posible!

Comment: Here is code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YoYUGb16wqin7G1l6q8V9eV2G1CvJzIX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You might not be able to add the dependency in the jar itself, but maybe point to a lib folder on the drive somewhere? that when it starts up it can load the lib? alternetavely you can add the required jar to the classpath when you run it i.e java.exe -classpath E:\lib\* Main or something of that sort. Though looking at your pom.xml i think you miss understood what the previous link was saying