# Java program and jar working on my PC but not on others people PCs

Tags: java, maven, jar

I stumbled with this issue today, the `jar` is packaged with all the necessary libs that the program uses (I'm using  `mvn clean compile assembly:single`) and this POM configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

The error(s) that show up are different, sometimes is the `NoSuchMethod` like the libraries weren't there but I decompress the `jar` and there they are, another error is `NoSuchFieldError`, but then again the `jar` and the program is the same, only when recompiled on that PC that I'm testing the program/`jar` it works.

So it's probably a thing from the IDE/environment config problem than my `jar` (that's my guess I can't really explain in other way).

What could the issue be?

**Edit:** added POM dependencies

```
</dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: what kind of dependencies do you have in your pom.xml?

Comment: added that info on the post

Comment: It could be due to the way you pack the jar, it could be because of your PATH variables versus others' and maybe you packaged files which you read in inside of your jar?

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg How i can check that?  i'm packing the jar like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019549/how-to-eclipse-maven-install-build-jar-with-dependencies

Comment: Sometimes, the JVM cannot locate certain resources such as dependent jars inside another jar. To overcome this problem, you can build a fat jar instead that contains all the classes required, flattened out to a single jar file. You can do this yourself, or there are tools such as sbt-assembly or sbt-onejar that allow you to do just that.

Comment: If you run `mvn clean compile assembly:single` you never reach the package-phase, hence the maven-shade-plugin is never called. I expect that the maven-shade-plugin results in a better fat jar compared to the maven-assembly-plugin, don't forget to mention the main-class here (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

Comment: Do those other PCs have the same JRE version?

Comment: @Roman yes, same version of java

Comment: You said that the errors differ among various machines. Still it might be interesting to see one example of a stacktrace. Could you please provide one?

Comment: @ThomasKuenneth the issue was solved repackaging all the jars with a new version number. not really sure about if it this was a real solution.